# Understanding of ajax complete call

Tags: javascript, ajax, selenium-webdriver

I'm struggling with stabilizing Selenium automation for jQuery/AJAX application hence referred to

https://www.swtestacademy.com/selenium-wait-javascript-angular-ajax/

and it has `ajaxComplete()` method which has following code -

```
var callback = arguments[arguments.length - 1];
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', '/Ajax_call', true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
   callback(xhr.responseText);
  }
};
xhr.send();
);
```

I haven't work on JavaScript before and this code which I'm not able to understand completely. I've following questions with this, if someone can help to understand it -

What is `Ajax_call` in this? Is it generic call to check ajax completion? Or do I need to have my own endpoint there? If yes, does single end point enough or do I need to identify all calls and add them in the method?

Comment: Ajax_call is just a placeholder for a URL that returns JSON/XML instead of HTML. Basically, it does a HTTP request (which is handled by the browser internally, not javascript) and hooks up the "request done" callback (onreadystatechange  == 4). When this occurs, it calls your javascript method "callback" with the data received.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the [documentation for XMLHttpRequest.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/open). If you do, you will the second argument listed is

> `url`
>
> A [DOMString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMString) representing the URL to send the request to.

This means that it is simply the URL you want to request. I can be anything you want. The `/` prefix means that you are request relative to the root of the website (so if you are requesting from `https://example.com/somedir/somepage` the request will be made to `https://example.com/Ajax_call`.